# Why am I getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm stuck in this project. Can someone help me out? I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
      String index out of range: 2
   at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
   at readFile.read(readFile.java:35)
   at readFile.main(readFile.java:90)
```

My code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

//import java.lang.*;

public class readFile {

    private Scanner x;
    public String[][] a;
    public String temp;
    public int surahNumber;

    public void openFile()
    {
        try{
            x  = new Scanner(new File("C:\\en.ahmedali.txt"));
            a = new String[500][1000];
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }

    }

    public void read()
    {

        int i = 1;
        int j = 1;
        String xy,tenToninetynie,three_digit,setsurahNumber1,setsurahNumber2,setsurahNumber3;

        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            a[i][j] = x.nextLine();
            temp = a[i][j];
            //System.out.println(temp);
            xy = temp.substring(1, 2);

            char[] charArray = xy.toCharArray();
            //System.out.println(xy);
            tenToninetynie = temp.substring(2, 3);
            char[] charArray1 = tenToninetynie.toCharArray();

            three_digit = temp.substring(3, 4);
            char[] charArray2 = three_digit.toCharArray();

            setsurahNumber1 = temp.substring(0, 1);
            setsurahNumber2 = temp.substring(0, 2);
            setsurahNumber3 = temp.substring(0, 3);

            if(charArray[0] == '|'){
                surahNumber = Integer.parseInt(setsurahNumber1);
                //System.out.println(surahNumber);
                if(surahNumber == i+1){
                    i++;
                    j = 0;
                }               
            }
            else if(charArray1[0] == '|'){
                surahNumber = Integer.parseInt(setsurahNumber2);
                //System.out.println(surahNumber);
                if(surahNumber == i+1){
                    i++;
                    j = 0;

                }
            }
            else if(charArray2[0] == '|'){
                surahNumber = Integer.parseInt(setsurahNumber3);
                //System.out.println(surahNumber);
                if(surahNumber == i+1){
                    //System.out.println("I See");
                    i++;
                    j = 0;              
                }
            }
            j++;
            //System.out.println(j);
            //break;

        }
    }
    void write()
    {
        System.out.println(a[75][1]);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        readFile y = new readFile();
        y.openFile();
        y.read();
        y.write();
        //System.out.println(y.a[75][1]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Well what value did you enter? Presumably a single character, which means that substring *will* fail when you ask for more than that...

Comment: Which line is line 35?

Comment: xy = temp.substring(1, 2);

Comment: getting value from a file..............
xy = temp.substring(1, 2); //Line 35

Comment: You should definitely add a check for the string length, e.g. `if( temp.length() >= 4)`, otherwise every empty line or line with less than 4 characters will produce an exception in your code.

Comment: @coder At StackOverflow we expect a certain amount of effort on the part of the questioner. In every case, you need to show what you've tried to do to solve your own problem. Looking through your questions to date, this is a crucial missing factor in all of them. I've voted to close this question as "too localized".

Comment: if( temp.length() >= 4),
has solved the problem...........
But it seems there is another problem............

the first line is missing in the array.............
example:
a[1][1] = 1|1|fhgfjfgjhgjhgjhg is missing
rather a[1][1] = 1|2|fhgfjfgjhgjhgjhg

Comment: I am confused about @DuncanJones .... As a new user in stackoverflow i might be missing something........... Sorry for my little knowledge...............
By the way i am a new java programmer......

Answer (score 0):

What does you en.ahmedali.txt file contains, probably it contains some line break and you are trying use substring using index, while it doesn't contains any, so you must check length of string first before call subString.

Comment: the file contains 
1|1|asdaskhdkj
1|2|asdaszxc
1|3|jxocvjxcjv
2|1|jojvkcxvn
2|2|joxzczxcz
3|1|bcxzjicjzkxbckjzxc
these type of lines........

Comment: 1|1|asdaskhdkj 1|2|asdaszxc 1|3|jxocvjxcjv 2|1|jojvkcxvn 2|2|joxzczxcz 3|1|bcxzjicjzkxbckjzxc these type of lines...

Comment: As mentioned earlier, you need to check existence of index of string before using subString on that, that will solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry for late reply...........I have solved it with checking length before substring.............Thanks everyone for your help.............